# How do you automatically close gaps in a complicated mesh?

Tags: mesh, retopology

I'm adjusting a complicated mesh, and I'm a blender noob. I cut the mesh to break the one mesh into two seperate objects, but now I'm trying to figure out how to reseal or close the area I cut.

In the attached image you can see the gap between the outside and inside walls.

Any help would be greatly appeciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi, to do the original cut you'd be better off using a boolean modifier. This has the added benefit of creating a flat bottom and filling the face for you. You can create a cube, scale and move it to where you want the cut to be, then use it as the tool for the boolean modifier.